# PHPunit is throwing error 'Version mismatch detected for the PHPUnit Polyfills. Please ensure that PHPUnit Polyfills 1.1.0 or higher is loaded'

Tags: php, composer-php, phpunit

This is on a Mac M1 running Ventura 13.1, PHP installed via HomeBrew.

PHP 7.4.33 (cli) (built: Sep  1 2023 02:37:00) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
with Xdebug v3.1.5, Copyright (c) 2002-2022, by Derick Rethans
with Zend OPcache v7.4.33, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies

Phpunit install via

```
composer require phpunit/phpunit
```

Error is

```
Error: Version mismatch detected for the PHPUnit Polyfills. Please ensure that PHPUnit Polyfills 1.1.0 or higher is loaded. Found version: 1.0.3
```

I tried:

```
 composer update --dev yoast/phpunit-polyfills --with-dependencies
```

as listed here https://github.com/Yoast/PHPUnit-Polyfills?tab=readme-ov-file#installation to no effect.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, here's a command to force install of the desired version

```
composer require --dev yoast/phpunit-polyfills:"^1.1.0"
```